# reload button in html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, console.log

I am trying to reload a button once it is clicked so that it will give more numbers.

```
<button onClick={console.log(0)}>zero</button>
<button onClick={console.log(1)}>one</button>
```

When I click it once it just gives me the number once in the console log.  How do you get it to give me more than one number?

Comment: What do you mean "give me more than one number"? Do you want the console.log function to change each time the button is clicked, or a new element to appear on the screen, or the text of the button should change?

Comment: I was wondering that each time the button is clicked it would give me the same number in the console log.  Not sure if it is possible or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: aah that makes sense - check Tobias's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a function to `onClick`, not the result of a single `console.log()`.

Try:

```
<button onClick={() => console.log(0)}>zero</button>
<button onClick={() => console.log(1)}>one</button>
```